# Create document id from two value fields separated by underscore using Elasticsearch Sink Connector for Kafka

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to load records from a Kafka topic to Elasticsearch using the Elasticsearch Sink Connector, but I'm struggling to construct the document ids the way I would like them. I would like the document id that is written to Elasticsearch to be a composition of two values separated by underscore from my kafka topic's message.

For example:

My Kafka topic value has the following Avro schema:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "SampleValue",
  "namespace": "com.abc.test",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "value1",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "int",
          "java-class": "java.lang.Integer"
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "value2",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "int",
          "java-class": "java.lang.Integer"
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "otherValue",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "int",
          "java-class": "java.lang.Integer"
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like the document id that is written to Elasticsearch to be the combined values of **value1** and **value2** separated by an underscore. If the given value in avro looked like

```
{"value1": {"int": 123}, "value2": {"int": 456}, "value3": {"int": 0}}
```

then I would like the document id for Elasticsearch to be `123_456`.

I can't figure out the correct way to chain transformations in my connector config to create a key that is composed of two values separated by an underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a Single Message Transform out of the box that will do what you want.

You can either write your own, using the Transform API, or you can use a stream processor such as Kafka Streams or ksqlDB.

Comment: Another option would be delegating this transformation to the Elastic Stack layer. You can create a ingest pipeline that performs the data change and then you could create a policy in Elasticsearch to execute this pipeline for the given index. Ideally the Elasticsearch connector for Kafka Connect should have a property to define which ingest pipeline to execute. More information here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html

Another option is using Logstash with groks in-between Kafka and Elasticsearch—but that would change your architecture a lot.